# Arguments in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there arguments that work most of the time in AS3? I want a code setup that will works most of the time. Any suggestions?

Books break it down, but don't show  how the programmers arrived at their conclusions. This could turn in to a discussion question, but if there's a secret I want to know.

**WHAT I'M AFTER**
- an argument structure
- learn a process to perform function calls
- expand variables beyond my "20 lines of code"
- manage variables, events, and functions systematically

**2 examples that do the same thing, but are structured different** "go figure"

```
//Example #1 "move the ball"
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop, false, 0, true);

function onLoop(evt:Event):void{
ball1.x += 5; 
 }


    //Example #1 "move the ball" 
    function moveBall(e:Event):void {
    ball2.x += 5;
    }
    ball2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBall);
```

**The if...else argument "ball loop"**

```
//growing collection of arguments
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myEnterFrame);
    function myEnterFrame(event:Event) {
    if (ball.x>800) {
    ball.x=-160;
    } else {
    ball.x+=5;
    }
    }
```

**DIFFERENT WAY OF DOING IT "from Adobe livedocs"**

```
EQUIVILANT BOOLEANS
var flag:Boolean = true;
var flag:Boolean = new Boolean(true);
var flag:Boolean = Boolean(true);

EQUIVILANT STRINGS
var str:String = new String("foo");
var str:String = "foo";
var str:String = String("foo");
```

**COMMENT**
a functional style like lambda calculus would be a good example "more math less syntax and class structures"

**EVENT LISTENERS**
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html

Comment: This makes my head hurt..I'm still learning too. Here's a good like about "functional programming" http://www.flashcodersny.org/wordpress/?p=166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you read up on event handlers on Adobe's site. http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000139.html

From the site, here is the function definition of addEventListener:

```
function addEventListener(eventName:String, 
                        listener:Object,
                        useCapture:Boolean=false,
                        priority:Integer=0,
                        useWeakReference:Boolean=false):Boolean;
```

The last three arguments have default values (false, 0, false) so those can be left out when you call the function. The first two arguments are always required.

I think that the rest of your question would be best answered by learning about object oriented programming in AS3. Here is one guide: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html

Comment: I strongly advise you understand what you're giving up if you leave useWeakReference as false. Many developers set this to True, because otherwise it can cause issues with memory management. It's a tangential issue and probably not something you'd need to worry about with small scale projects, but Grant Skinner sets his to true if that carries any weight for you: http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_weakly_refe.html

Comment: You are correct. I left that there since those are the default values and I did not want to overly complicate the answer. If at any point in a program an event listener is no longer needed the programmer should call removeEventListener(eventName:String, 
                        listener:Object) or set useWeakReference true to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, many developers prefer to set useWeakReference to true, which requires that you plug in all five arguments into event listeners. The reason is that that way the listener doesn't hold a reference to the target that would prevent garbage collection - it's a memory management technique. Most really good AS3 devs will tell you to always use all five arguments, just to get to that point.

Also, generally speaking it's better to use a literal when you can. "text" instead of new String("text"), true instead of new Boolean(true). Complex reasons, but there's your short answer.

The answers to a lot of these questions can be found [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions), which is a document that attempts to standardize AS3 coding conventions. It's worth reading over!

Comment: what i needed! useWeakReferences true takes out the trash http://onflash.org/ted/2008/09/useweakreferencesboolean-false.php